# What is the word for the act of drawing air through your mouthful of wine?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some wine tasters will take a sip of wine and suck air through it making a slurping bubbling sound.

What is the word for it?

Comment: Have you tried synonyms for _slurp_? Have you tried looking on specialist wine sites?

Answer (score 1):

Wine tasting involves the nose, the tongue, and retronasal passage.  When a sommelier slurps wine, it is to smell the aromas of the warmed wine that is in the mouth.  This technique is *"retronasal breathing."*  When a sip of wine is in the mouth, a gentle inhale (usually through pursed lips) over the wine allows subtle aromas to be "tasted" by olfactory cells as the aroma passes through the retronasal passage in the back of the throat up to the sinus cavity. It can be a noisy technique, but quite effective.

Two sources to consider:
A scientific article from the Flavour Journal:
https://flavourjournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13411-014-0030-9
and
A less formal discussion on the Wine Folly site, with some visuals:
https://winefolly.com/deep-dive/science-of-wine-tasting/

Comment: A reference would make this a truly perfect answer.

Comment: @GlobalCharm ... Thank you for your suggestion.  I found a couple references that I believe may be helpful and added them as you rightly suggest.